# How to write for loop for iterating a DataFrame and subset it to include only those columns that are retrieved at each iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, conditional-statements, subset

[image: similar to excel filter option]

The aim is to get a subset DataFrame such as with three columns after each iteration
'id', 'reference','sample 1' when sample 1 is 0 (do this for every sample)
'id', 'reference','sample 1' when sample 1 is 1 (do this for every sample)
example when sample 1 = 0, the resulting subset DataFrame would be
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sample_cols = df.columns[2:]
dfs = []
for col in sample_cols:
    print('='*50, col, '='*50)
    for condition in [0, 1]:
        print('='*20, condition, '='*20)
        df_subset = df[df[col]==condition].reset_index(drop=True)
        df_subset = df_subset[['id', 'Reference', col]]
        print(df_subset)
        #df_subset.to_csv(f'./{col}_{condition}.csv', index=False)
        dfs.append(df_subset)

df_final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df_final.to_csv('./file_name.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked...you saved my day. the code is neat and clear. can i ask you more, how to iteratively store the results to dataframe or csv? if this is not bothering you... thanks again

Comment: also when i tried with more samples it stopped after 5 samples and throwing error.[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './6|Central Asia/Southern Siberia Russia  Cossacks lower Don|_0.csv'

Comment: Its because you have slashes in your column names.  You can try saving the files with different naming.

Comment: You can try the updated solution to get one csv but that csv file will be sparse.

Comment: thank you sir. it solved my issue. im glad and thanks again. i want to be a better programmer, can you suggest ideas. since i feel your code is simple yet powerful..i find this interesting

Comment: Check this: https://www.kaggle.com/learn

Comment: as in the code, in the 5th line, can i have the condition as if it is a string match between the sample _cols and reference instead of 0,1,2 etc.,